# Get Input coordinates to show markers on map in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

Can anybody write some code to get input(coordinates) from user to show as marker on map and continue adding markers with new lat,long and option to delete marker too.
Please.

I have written this code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOaIH.png)

Comment: Did you try to make any effort?

Comment: Yes, I have but it after effort of whole day when I feed it to the Marker it cause error in whole application, that's why I thought guys here will write some quality code, please

Answer (score 1):

This code should works, let me know if not.

```
const [position,setPosition] = useState([]);

const getLocation = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            setPosition([pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude]);
        },);
```

Comment: I was talking about input coordinates from any input field, where user can enter coordinates and it keep on displaying marker with every new entry

Comment: You want to ask lat long at user and then put a marker at this position ?

Comment: User will input any coordinate as lat,long and this component will add marker on entered coordinates

Comment: So input coordinate and then add marker to your map as it show on the doc https://react-leaflet.js.org/